# What creature does the dinosaur-like skull on Ahch-To belong to?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, object-identification, animals

Here's a screenshot. You can see it in *The Last Jedi* in the brief underwater shot when Rey falls into the dark side well. It's immediately preceding the famous "mirror Reys" scene; on the Blu-Ray, it's at the 1:13:56 mark.

[image: dark photo of the skull in question at the bottom of the cave pool in the lower right corner with Rey swimming past in center]

I was unable to find any reference to what that skull, very much resembling a T-Rex, lying at the bottom of the pool, might be. This isn't something that can get into a shot by accident, it had to be designed and placed, so there must be *some* background to it.

So, what's the in-universe and out-of-universe story on that skull?

Comment: A quick look at the Visual Dictionary and the Incredible Cross-sections for ep. VIII  shows nothing about this creature, and it is not mentioned on the Wookieepedia page for that film either.

Comment: There's a shot earlier in the movie (I think near the start) where Rey is talking to Luke part-way up a hill, with the shot facing the water, and in the background you see a large reptilian animal surface and dive under again. Likely the same species?

Answer (score 1):

**Perhaps a Pallaskean?**

[image]

Of the known creatures of Ahch-To, the [Pallaskean](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pallaskean) is the only one of comparable size to the skeleton. It also shares the skull's elongated form and sharp teeth. As an aquatic creature, it's location underwater also makes since. It first appeared in the comic *[Life Lessons](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Life_Lessons)*.

That said, it appears the creature was inspired by a similar sea serpent from the *Holiday Special* and not intentionally based on the skull from *The Last Jedi*. However, no official word on the skull seems to exist, so this is our best bet for now.